# How can I create a loop in my Graphviz flowchart?

Tags: loops, graphviz, flowchart

I am trying to create a flowchart with nodes in set positions. I am using invisible nodes to try and force the direction of edges. My diagram is below.
Its not quite right as I am wanting the lines coming out from node `d` , and around to the edge from `c` to `d` to be continuous (and straight).

How can I make it so that the lines all join? Thanks

[image]

My code to reproduce

```
digraph g1 {

  graph [splines=false];

  // invisible nodes
  node[fontsize=15, shape = box, width=3, height=0] ;
  i1 [ style="invis"];
  i2 [ style="invis"];
  i3 [ style="invis"];
  i4 [ style="invis"];

  node[fontsize=15, color = black, shape = box, width=3, height=1] ;
  a[color=blue, label="a"];
  b[color=green, label="b"];
  c[color=orange, label="c"]; 
  d[color=red, label="d"] ;       

  {rank=same; a -> b -> c};

  {rankdir = TB;    c -> i1[arrowhead=none];
        i1 -> d[label="  FOR EACH\n\n"]; 
        d -> i2[arrowhead=none];
  };

  {rank=same; i3 -> i2[arrowhead=none] };

  {rankdir = TB; 
    b -> i4[style="invis"];
    i4 -> i3[arrowhead=none];
  };

  {rank=same; i4 -> i1};

}
```

Following Paul's comment I tried using `node[fontsize=15, shape = box, label="", width=0, height=0, fixedsize=true]` which resulted in

[image]

Comment: It looks like the invisible nodes' size is causing the arrows to start in "mid-air". I would try something like  `node[shape = box, width=0, height=0 fixedsize=true] ;` for the invisible nodes, but I cannot try it out right now.

Comment: Thanks @PaulR ; I have edited the question with your suggestion. It seems by setting width and height to zero changes how the nodes are positioned.

Comment: Ah, I see... Maybe you can use the [ranksep](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:ranksep) attribute with "equally" to influence the spacing.

Comment: thanks @PaulR, I'll give that a go.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using `shape = points` and `minlen` comes to the rescue:

```
digraph g1 {

  graph [splines=false];

  // invisible nodes
  node[ shape = point, width=0, height=0] ;
  i1 [ style="invis"];
  i2 [ style="invis"];
  i3 [ style="invis"];
  i4 [ style="invis"];

  node[fontsize=15, color = black, shape = box, width=3, height=1] ;
  a[color=blue, label="a"];
  b[color=green, label="b"];
  c[color=orange, label="c"]; 
  d[color=red, label="d"] ;       

  {rank=same; a -> b -> c};

  c -> i1[arrowhead=none];
  i1 -> d[label="  FOR EACH\n\n"]; 
  d -> i2[arrowhead=none];

  {rank=same; i3 -> i2[arrowhead=none, minlen = 7 ] };

  b -> i4[style="invis"];
  i4 -> i3[arrowhead=none];

  {rank=same; i4 -> i1};

}
```

yields

[image]

Comment: Thanks vaettchen, looks good. was `minlen=7` trail and error please?

Comment: Yes it was. It happens to be 3 + 3 + 1 (width of your box times 2, plus 1 space) but not sure whether that's coincidence...